# How to realize the automatic jump to the specified page

Tags: ios

i want to do a function,that is in page-based,i add a button,when i click the button,pop-up a Select box.In the selected box input the page number,but how can i realize that when i input the page number,the page  jump to the specified page

edit:

I want to do a calendar,the label title bar in the top i have used button,now,it is that when i press the button,it will pop up a marquee,in there have month.now ,i want to press a month in the press box,then turn to the corresponding page.

Comment: need some more info. What kind of app is this? What exactly is a page?

Comment: I hardly think having to input a page number is "Automatic". Hopefully you realize that too